# Criar índices dinamicamente com javascript

Tags: javascript

Bom dia senhores,

Estou criando um sistema de contratos e e estou com uma dúvida de como realizar uma certa ideia.

Como o contrato funciona por clausuras e parágrafos,  preciso adicionar índices dinamicamente.

A ideia seria assim:

```
1 - Primeira Clausura.
1.1 - Primeiro paragrafo.
1.2 - Segundo Paragrafo
...

2 - Segunda Clausura.
2.1 - Primeiro paragrafo da segunda clausura.
2.2 - Segundo paragrafo da segunda clausura.
...

3 - Terceira Clausura.
3.1 - Terceiro paragrafo da Terceira clausura.
3.2 - STerceiro paragrafo da Terceira clausura.
...
```

Eu tenho uma função js que adiciona esses parágrafos através de um textarea, ou seja não grava em banco e não recebe nada de banco, então caso o usuário deletar o paragrafo `2.1` por exemplo, o paragrafo `2.2` passa automaticamente a ser `2.1`.

Bom qualquer ideia já ajuda bastante, desde já agradeço! Abraço!

Comment: Se você não usa banco, onde está gravando? Ou se puder dar mais detalhes, não entendi direito a questão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar [uma RegExp para procurar índices](https://regex101.com/r/iG1iF6/1) e substituílos por ordem crescente. Seria algo assim:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('contrato');
var clausulas = new RegExp('([0-9\.]+)\\s\\-', 'g');
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    var texto = this.value;
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var subIndex = 0;
    this.value = texto.replace(clausulas, function (match) {
        if (match.indexOf('.') == -1) {
            currentIndex++;
            subIndex = 0;
            return currentIndex + ' -';
        }
        subIndex++;
        return [currentIndex, '.', subIndex, ' -'].join('');
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9hh5amko/

O JavaScript tem uma função nativa para substituições. Passando-lhe uma função como segundo parametro podes trabalhar cada valor encontrado pela regex.

Dentro da função separei em 2 tipos. Os que têm `.` (subIndex)  e o que não têm (currentIndex) e dessa maneira vão aumentando deixando tudo ordenado.